# `Convert` and standard output

Tags: pipe, stdout, conversion, imagemagick

I am learning how to use terminal and as an exercise tried to convert a bunch of .png images to ASCII-art using `convert` and `jp2a` with this command:

```
convert test.png -format jpg - | jp2a -
```

This results in error message, indicating that `jp2a` receives a .png file:

```
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50
```

As I understood, `convert` with `-` argument outputs both the input and the output  files. Is it possible to pipe only the converted file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
convert test.png jpg:- | jp2a -
```